# Python Array Unexpected Overwrite

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, arraylist

i have a question about python list, I want to generate a array like (001, 002, 011, 012) when i try to add a list to list, a new list try to overwrite old element

```
n = 3
def setNextCombination(P):
    idx = len(P) - 1
    while True:       
        if idx == 0:
            break
        if P[idx] < idx:
            P[idx] += 1
            curr = idx + 1
            while curr < len(P):
                P[curr] = P[idx]
                curr += 1
            return P, True
        idx -= 1
    return [], False

def path_choosing():
    P = np.zeros(n, dtype=int)
    flag = True
    arr = [0,0,0,0]
    idx = 0
    while True:
        P, flag = setNextCombination(P)
        if(flag == False): break
        arr[idx] = P
        idx += 1
        print(idx)
        print(arr)
path_choosing()
```

Actual Output:

```
1
[array([0, 0, 1]), 0, 0, 0]
2
[array([0, 0, 2]), array([0, 0, 2]), 0, 0]
3
[array([0, 1, 1]), array([0, 1, 1]), array([0, 1, 1]), 0]
4
[array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2])]
```

My excepted output

```
1
[array([0, 0, 1]), 0, 0, 0]
2
[array([0, 0, 1]), array([0, 0, 2]), 0, 0]
3
[array([0, 0, 1]), array([0, 0, 2]), array([0, 1, 1]), 0]
4
[array([0, 0, 1]), array([0, 0, 2]), array([0, 1, 1]), array([0, 1, 2])]
```

i dont know how, please help me

Comment: i will be edit my tag

Comment: Arrays and lists are different things. Also, you seem to be expecting pass-by-value semantics, where passing an object to a function would make a copy of that object. That's not how Python works. Have a quick guide to how passing objects around actually works in Python: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
P = np.zeros(n, dtype=int)
```

This is where you created a numpy array in memory. You're passing a reference to this array, 'P', to the setNextCombination method, and that makes changes to it. You never actually create a new array in memory, so when you do `arr[idx] = P`, you're pointing to the same array in memory every time.

You should pass a copy of your np array to setNextCombination instead. You could use [numpy.copy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html) for this. Alternatively, look up the `copy` module in python.

Comment: This is not a list.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica thank you, it worked but i want to another solution not using copy module

Comment: @ttdat-thecodeguy You can use numpy.copy too: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html. Updated my answer

Comment: @entropy thank for your help